# How to remove unwanted files(100's in number) from git add list

Tags: git, github

I have around 30 files in the local repo that I needed to push to the server. But when I do git add . >> git commit -a "msg"... a large number of files also getting committed along with that. How do I remove those files?

What I have tried:

Adding all those wanted 30 files individually using git add and then committing. But still all those unwanted file added along.
git reset HEAD~ >> git add . >> git commit. But issue still the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "add 30 files invidually using git add"? I can only see the command `git add .` in the question, and no command for "add ... invidually".

Comment: individually as in : git add <file>... for all desired files. But still all unwanted file gets committed once I use git commit -a " " thereafter

Comment: Do you execute `git add .` between `git reset` and `git commit`?

Comment: Yes I did execute that

Comment: You can use git clean which is only for untracked files `git clean -d -f `  d for directory and f for file

Comment: clean will remove only untracked files..but some files are coming out of nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend here that you just run `git add` only on the files which you actually want to add to the stage.  One option which I use often is to just type `git status` from the Git bash, and then copy the list of files to an editor such as Notepad++.  From there, it is easy enough to prepend a `git add` before each listed file name.  Then, you only need to copy this list back to the bash, and all your files should be added.

Note that most of the time if you only have a handful of files to add, you may just type them out manually in the bash, and it is not too much of a headache.

Comment: I already tried this but once I do git commit after adding the desired file, I see all other files getting committed

Comment: Well in Git a commit generally is always a snapshot of _all_ the files in your repository.  You can't just commit a subset of the files in your repo.  If you are seeing files being committed which you did not `git add` or modify, then something is wrong and you did not follow my suggestion exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `git commit -a` you're doing afterwards. The `-a` parameter adds every change in the working directory to the index before committing.

Add each file separately, or do a `git add .` followed by some specific `git reset HEAD -- <file>`, either way's fine, but at the end do NOT use the `-a` parameter for your commit.

Reminder : `git status` lists files ready for commit and unstaged changes as two separate lists. So make sure you're fine with the list before your commit.

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA Make sure that the list of files ready for commit is fine to you with `git status` then just `git commit -m "your message"` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I got this message after using -m " 30 files changed, 411 insertions(+), 204 deletions". Does this means in those 30 file there have been 411 insertions and 204 deletions or it means other than these 30 files 411 more files has been added and 204 files has been deleted as compared to server version

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA No, this is the line count for the changes : 411 lines added, 204 deleted. If you want to make sure what exactly has been commited, do a `git show HEAD^`. But if you intended to commit 30 files, this seems like the desired output to me :-)